# Hypercylic operators have very typical cyclic vectors

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let $W$ be the Wiener measure on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and let $T\in L(C_0(\mathbb{R}),C_0(\mathbb{R}))$ be a hypercylic operator; i.e. there exists some $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\{T^n(f)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.  Then, is it true that:
$$
W(\left\{f\in C_0(\mathbb{R}):\, \overline{\text{span}(\{T^n(f)\}_{n=1}^{\infty})}=C_0(\mathbb{R})\right\})=1?
$$